# How to display the data from the form 1 into the form 2

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I want to select 3 columns from the database on 'form 1' which is firstname, username and rolename to display it on form 2.
The firstname and username are display on the form 2, but the rolename is not appear, is there error on my code? 
The error in the picture in form 2 at part rolename suppose to be display "lab user on liquid"/"lab user on raw food".

[image: form1 and form 2]

## FORM 1

```
 namespace labuser
 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {               
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=AlcoholSystem;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select firstname,rolename from tblUser where username='" + username.Text + "' and password = '" + password.Text + "'", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);


        if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username and password is correct.");
            this.Hide();
            Form2 ss = new Form2(username.Text, dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
            ss.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please check your username and password!");
        }
    }
```

## FORM 2

```
namespace labuser
{
   public partial class Form2 : Form
  {
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=AlcoholSystem;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    DataTable table = new DataTable();


    string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

    public Form2(String Username, String firstname, String rolename)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        label5.Text = Username;
        label8.Text = firstname;
        label13.Text = rolename;


        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass rolename as third param as

```
Form2 ss = new Form2(username.Text, dt.Rows[0][0].ToString(), dt.Rows[0][1].ToString());
```